# Asynchronous requests backoff/throttling best practice

Tags: python, rest, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

**Scenario**: I need to gather paginated data from a web app's API which has a call limit of 100 per minute. The API object I need to return contains 100 items per page for 105 total, and growing, pages (~10,500 total items). Synchronous code was taking approximately 15 minutes to retrieve all the pages, so there was no worry about hitting the call limits then. However, I wanted to speed up the data retrieval, so I implemented asynchronous calls using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. Data now downloads in 15 seconds - nice.

**Problem**: I'm now hitting the call limit thus receiving 403 errors for the last 5 or so calls.

**Proposed Solution** I implemented the `try/except` found in the `get_data()` function. I make the calls, and then when the call is not successful because of `403: Exceeded call limit` I back off for `back_off` seconds and retry up to `retries` times:

```
async def get_data(session, url):
    retries = 3
    back_off = 60  # seconds to try again
    for _ in range(retries):
        try:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
                if response.status != 200:
                    response.raise_for_status()
                print(retries, response.status, url)
                return await response.json()
        except aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError as e:
            retries -= 1
            await asyncio.sleep(back_off)
            continue

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        attendee_urls = get_urls('attendee') # returns list of URLs to call asynchronously in get_data()
        attendee_data = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, attendee_url) for attendee_url in attendee_urls])
        return attendee_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = asyncio.run(main())
```

**Question**: How do I limit the aiohttp calls so that they stay under the 100 calls/minute threshold without making a 403 request to back off? I've tried the following modules and none of them appeared to do anything: `ratelimiter`, `ratelimit` and `asyncio-throttle`.

**Goal**: To make 100 async calls per minute, but backing off and retrying if necessary (403: Exceeded call limit).

Comment: There may be a better way to do this, and you're right to ask, but in a philosophical sense the constraints of the business domain don't always map neatly on to the tools our technology gives us. Sometimes you do really have to kludge it, just make sure you document *why*.

Comment: @JaredSmith And I would be OK with that for this particular scenario because I am working with a relatively small amount of data, so there probably isn't much of an impact for now. However, my concern is with "future proofing" because the possibility of this object growing larger is certainly there. The part where I mention the 1000 page scenario in my **Question** is what concerns me the most.

Comment: The other question is, what's the gain in not hitting the call limit? This is a totally expected outcome that you cannot prevent (in fact, someone else/another process might be chipping away from your allotment without you noticing). The API server counts that so you don't have to, and ultimately it is the only authority in this scenario. I would request away until I hit the limit and then back off. That's a part of life, trying to avoid it won't work reliably, so you might as well factor it in.

Comment: @Tomalak Right, and in the case that something else is chipping away unknowingly, then hitting the 403 and trying again makes sense - in that case you don't KNOW you're going to hit a limit. But bursting the callee when you KNOW there are going to be 403s is unnecessary. I, again, use the example of what if I had 1000 pages each containing 100 items of data. I get the 1st page, spam 99 pages to get their 403, wait 60 seconds, get the 2nd page, spam 98 pages to get their 403s, wait 60 seconds, get the 3rd page.. etc.. How is this scenario possibly a "totally expected outcome"?

Comment: @Tomalak The gain is not unnecessarily spamming calls to a service that I know are going to receive a 403 because I've already been rate limited.

Comment: Yes, that's why you back off as soon as you get the first such response. My point is, the 403 is not an exceptional scenario from the server's point of view, it's a normal part of operation. You can use it for flow control, you don't have to bend over backwards to avoid 403 responses. Of course you would back off immediately and *wouldn't* spam the remaining 99 calls in a batch. (Some APIs even tell you how many seconds you need to back off via the headers.)

Comment: I _shouldn't_ spam the remaining 99 calls but **I DO** currently - the code I've posted demonstrates that. That's what I'm trying to avoid. The backoff is applied per awaited object in `asyncio.gather()`

Comment: You could set up some shared state between the workers - I've found this: https://addshore.com/2018/06/python3-using-some-shared-state-in-2-async-methods/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve "at most 100 requests/min" by adding a delay before every request.

100 requests/min is equivalent to 1 request/0.6s.

```
async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        attendee_urls = get_urls('attendee') # returns list of URLs to call asynchronously in get_data()
        coroutines = []
        for attendee_url in attendee_urls:
            coroutines.append(asyncio.Task(get_data(session, attendee_url)))
            await asyncio.sleep(0.6)
        attendee_data = asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
        return attendee_data
```

Apart from the request rate limit, often, APIs also limit the no. of simultaneous requests. If so, you can use [BoundedSempahore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#boundedsemaphore).

```
async def main():
    sema = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(50) # Assuming a concurrent requests limit of 50
...
            coroutines.append(get_data(sema, session, attendee_url))
...

def get_data(sema, session, attendee_url):

...

    for _ in range(retries):
        try:
            async with sema:
                response = await session.get(url, headers=headers):
                if response.status != 200:
                    response.raise_for_status()
...
```